# How to set timeout on ADO.NET + EF6 + WCF DataService 5.6?

Tags: entity-framework-6, ado, wcf-data-services

I have an issue where a select query against a huge table times out. I want to increase the timeout, but i can't do it via the C# code, because the only C# code i have is the single method in my service cs file which looks like follows.

```
public class myodataapi : EntityFrameworkDataService< my_DWHEntities1 >
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    }
}
```

This is really the only CS file i have, my OData Api works fine but ends with an error because of an timeout. How can i set the timeout here. And having a logging feature to see all generated SQL would be great, but i have no flipping idea how to do it, because all solutions i found on the web are related to a so called "dBContext" class which i don't have here.

Comment: Do you want to set timeout in EF6 or set timeout in WCF DataService 5.6?

Comment: Well, if you ask me for both, then it makes sense to have the timeout set on both. But the error is thrown from ef6.

Comment: Is your error caused by the client or the server?Can you throw your error?